Adding an index to query result
I have a table that contains dates, a column that holds several book titles an finally a column that contains the sales quantity per title. On any given day, anywhere between 1 and 10 titles can have sales. Maybe 'Title 1' 10 pieces, 'Title 3' 5 pieces and 'Title 4' 15 pieces. On another day, maybe there are sales only for Title 2 and 7 etc.
Now, focusing on those days where more than 1 title was sold, I can select the date, the title and the sales quantity with an [ORDER BY] sales quantity and indeed the result is a table that has an implied top sales per day via the ordering clause. But what if I also need an index per title so that, for example, I can see day by day the position of say Title 3? Is it possible to add to the query result such a simple index?
So what I hope to achieve is a query result as below:



Date
Title
Index
Sales




15 AUG 2024
Title 2
1
125


15 AUG 2024
Title 4
2
100


15 AUG 2024
Title 5
3
90


15 AUG 2024
Title 9
4
50


16 AUG 2024
Title 1
1
230


16 AUG 2024
Title 2
2
150


16 AUG 2024
Title 7
3
100


17 AUG 2024
Title 4
1
50


17 AUG 2024
Title 9
2
20



etc.
I'm using MS ACCESS with VB.NET and struggled to find a way.
Thanks

Use my function RowNumber.

As I understood you want index per date order by sale of particular book title,
For that you can use window function row_number()
SELECT Date, Title, Sales, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Sales DESC) as index from {tableName}


Not in MS Access, it's not supported.

You can use subquery to calculate number of Titles, whose sales are higher than the current line. This will get the row rank (index) you are looking for.
If 2 titles have same sales quantity, they will get the same index. You can additionally rank, for example, by name, if necessary.
See example
SELECT t1.*,
  (select count(*) from DateTitleIndexSales as t2 
   where t2.SalesDate=t1.SalesDate 
     and (t2.sales>t1.sales or (t2.sales=t1.sales and t2.title<t1.title))
   )+1 as index
FROM DateTitleIndexSales as t1
order by SalesDate, Sales desc,Title ;



Great guidance, thanks. Unfortunately, ROW_NUMBER() does not work in MS ACCESS (why am I not surprised). But checking if there is a way around this limitation, I found out an older Stack Overflow thread which deals precisely with this issue:
Achieving ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY in MS Access

Perhaps your comment refers to another answer to your question. row_number() is not in Access, and in my response I suggest replacing this function by subquery.

I think you meant t2.title<>t1.title

No, I think t2.title<t1.title. There is a need for certainty of order. If we take ('Title 1',100) and ('Title 2',100), we need to determine the order between them. I arbitrarily take that Title 1 before Title 2. Or as row_number()over(partition by SalesDate order by sales desc,title asc)

And, if we remove condition or (t2.sales=t1.sales and t2.title<t1.title) row_number() turns into rank()

@ValNik - Yes, I think that was mistake, being very curious about a solution I must have read your answer and Mit Shah's thinking they were both from you. As for your solution, I tried it but strange enough the machine keeps computing and computing (no errors) for minutes...it is true that I used your query on table that results from another query, not a stored table. Maybe this is the problem. I will try after having saved the data to a table first.

It's hard to say anything without seeing the full query or the sequence of queries. However, an index by SalesDate in the source table would be very useful. How big is the initial source data?
